# refresh a pixel art array swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

is there anyway of refreshing the code to update , when the uiColorArray array variable changes

view code:

```
   var body: some View {

        let cellCount = 32
       
        VStack(spacing:1) {
            ForEach(1...cellCount, id:\.self) { r in
                HStack(spacing:1) {
                    ForEach(1...cellCount, id:\.self) { c in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color(uiColorArray[c+r]))
                                .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }.gesture(drag)}
}
```

array declaration :

```
public var uiColorArray = [UIColor](){
    didSet {
        print("arrayChanged")
    }
```

any help would be nice thanks in advance...

the array to refresh the screen

Comment: Where is the array declared? Also where do you change it? If it's local to the view then `@State` would be enough to trigger a redraw.

Comment: declared at line 12 var uiColorArray = [UIColor]()

Comment: I added the line:
    @State public var uiColorArraycopy = uiColorArray and refectored for this still no joy :S

Comment: it updates once but when I click the pixels don't update, anyway to refresh with a click the main body view?

Comment: any way to refresh using a timer maybe>

Comment: okay I did as suggested but the app just won't start now!

Comment: Hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here. Please add what you have changed as edit to your question. Please elaborate a bit more of what you want your code to do. What error do you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884419/switch-between-array-structs-keeping-data - the code working is here, but with a new problem...