# Switch between array structs keeping data

Tags: ios, swiftui, pixel

the data is not stored between switching grids..

switching grids in the list and they came out blank when I swapped
its a pixelart creator I could do with it having slices totalling 32 and
save between switching...

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentViewBFiverr: View { // help from the guy a fiverr.
    @State var slice_number = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("gridImage").zIndex(-1.0).frame(width: 320, height: 480, alignment: .center).offset(x: 0, y: -220.0)
                .clipped()
        VStack{
            if slice_number == 0 {
                Grid()
                
            }
            if slice_number == 1 {
                Grid2()
                
            }
            ColorPalette()
            Picker("Test:", selection: $slice_number) {
                ForEach(1..<33) { i in
                    Text(String(i)).fontWeight(.ultraLight).font(.footnote)
                }
            
            }.offset(x: 0.0, y: 50.0).frame(width: 320, height: 100, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }
        }
    }
}


var color_changer = Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0)
let numOfRowsAndColumns = 32
let sizeOfCell = CGFloat(10.0)
// grid1
struct Grid: View {
    @State private var cells: [[Cell]] = (0..<numOfRowsAndColumns).map { _ in
        (0..<numOfRowsAndColumns).map { _ in Cell() }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(cells.indices, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(cells[row], id: \.id) { cell in
                        CellView(cell: cell)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.0))
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    let x = Int(value.location.x / CGFloat(sizeOfCell))
                    let y = Int(value.location.y / CGFloat(sizeOfCell))
                    if x >= 0 && x < numOfRowsAndColumns && y >= 0 && y < numOfRowsAndColumns {
                        self.cells[y][x].color = color_changer
                        
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}

// grid1
struct Grid2: View {
    @State private var cells2: [[Cell]] = (0..<numOfRowsAndColumns).map { _ in
        (0..<numOfRowsAndColumns).map { _ in Cell() }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(cells2.indices, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(cells2[row], id: \.id) { cell in
                        CellView(cell: cell)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.0))
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    let x = Int(value.location.x / CGFloat(sizeOfCell))
                    let y = Int(value.location.y / CGFloat(sizeOfCell))
                    if x >= 0 && x < numOfRowsAndColumns && y >= 0 && y < numOfRowsAndColumns {
                        self.cells2[y][x].color = color_changer
                        
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}

struct CellView: View {
    var cell: Cell
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(cell.color)
            Rectangle()
                .stroke()
                .fill(Color.white)
        }.frame(width: sizeOfCell, height: sizeOfCell)
    }
}

struct Cell: Identifiable {
    var color: Color = Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.1)
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ColorPalette: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.red).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.green).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.1, blue: 0.9, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.1, blue: 0.9, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.4, blue: 0.7, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.4, blue: 0.7, opacity: 1.0)
                }

        }
        //second row of colors
        HStack{
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.3, green: 0.1, blue: 0.2, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.3, green: 0.1, blue: 0.2, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.4, blue: 0.1, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.4, blue: 0.1, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.7, blue: 0.9, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.7, blue: 0.9, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.4, green: 0.4, blue: 0.1, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.4, green: 0.4, blue: 0.1, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.25, green: 0.25, blue: 0.25, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.25, green: 0.25, blue: 0.25, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.7, blue: 0.2, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.7, blue: 0.2, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.1, blue: 0.3, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.1, blue: 0.3, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.7, green: 0.4, blue: 0.6, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.7, green: 0.4, blue: 0.6, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            
            
        }
        HStack{
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.3, blue: 0.3, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.3, blue: 0.3, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.8, green: 1.0, blue: 0.8, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.8, green: 1.0, blue: 0.8, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.7, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.7, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.5, blue: 0.4, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.5, blue: 0.4, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.2, blue: 0.5, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.2, blue: 0.5, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.8, blue: 0.6, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.8, blue: 0.6, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.8, blue: 0.5, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.8, blue: 0.5, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, opacity: 1.0)).frame(width: 10, height: 10).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, opacity: 1.0)
                }
            Image("transparentPixel")
                .font(.system(size: 20)).onTapGesture {
                    color_changer = Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 0.0)
                }
            
            
            
        }
         
        }
}
```

any help would be nice...

switching grids in the list and they came out blank when I swapped
its a pixelart creator I could do with it having slices totalling 32 and
save between switching...

Comment: I get why it isn't keeping the data, im just not sure the way to go about saving it

Comment: There's a lot of code there and it isn't particularly  well formatted (Hint select all and use ctrl-i in Xcode) and I am not sure of your exact problem, but I am going to guess that it is because you are using `@State` - You will need a data model to store your data independent of the view and refer to it via `@StateObject` or similar

Comment: so Im guessing that I could copy the data by adding "var copy_number_one = [[Cell]]()" at the top of the code and "copy_number_one = cells" in the drag gesture . on changed, but not sure how to put it back into the @state cells varaiable , just an idea though.. im new to swift its different from java could .. add a function that adds it.

Answer (score 0):

This is way out of the scope for Stack Overflow but I remember you already posted some questions regarding the task you are working on.

To begin with; you need to define your source of truth for SwiftUI using models, not states. States are those that handle your models.

The example I made goes like this:

A canvas model:

```
class Canvas: ObservableObject {
    
    let width: Int
    let height: Int
    
    @Published private(set) var colors: [Color]
    
    init(width: Int, height: Int, defaultColor: Color = .white) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.colors = .init(repeating: defaultColor, count: width*height)
    }

    func colorAt(x: Int, y: Int) -> Color {
        guard x >= 0, x < width else { return .clear }
        guard y >= 0, y < height else { return .clear }
        return colors[y*width + x]
    }

    func applyColor(_ color: Color, at position: (x: Int, y: Int)) {
        guard position.x >= 0, position.x < width else { return }
        guard position.y >= 0, position.y < height else { return }
        colors[position.y*width + position.x] = color
    }
    
}
```

I cerated a model that holds all your canvas data. It has a fixed width and height and an array of colors, marked as "published" so it will reflect changes in SwiftUI. All the convenience methods are exposed.

To draw this canvas I create a simple view

```
struct CanvasView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var canvas: Canvas
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<canvas.height, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<canvas.width, id: \.self) { column in
                            canvas.colorAt(x: column, y: row)
                                .frame(width: proxy.size.width/CGFloat(canvas.width),
                                       height: proxy.size.height/CGFloat(canvas.height))
                                .border(Color.white, width: 1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CanvasView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CanvasView(canvas: .init(width: 10, height: 10, defaultColor: .blue))
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 300))
    }
}
```

This view doesn't do anything but draw your data. We will handle events elsewhere.

A simple color picker needs `@Binding` to change your color:

```
struct ColorPickerView: View {

    @Binding var selectedColor: Color
    let colors: [Color]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                ForEach(colors.indices, id: \.self) { colorIndex in
                    Button {
                        selectedColor = colors[colorIndex]
                    } label: {
                        if colors[colorIndex] == selectedColor {
                            colors[colorIndex]
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                        } else {
                            colors[colorIndex]
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ColorPickerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ColorPickerView(selectedColor: .constant(.blue), colors: [.red, .green, .blue, .orange])
    }
}
```

Now since you have multiple canvases I introduced a model that holds those canvases

```
class CanvasScene: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var canvases: [Canvas]
    @Published var selectedCanvasIndex: Int
    
    init(canvases: [Canvas], selectedCanvasIndex: Int = 0) {
        self.canvases = canvases
        self.selectedCanvasIndex = selectedCanvasIndex
    }
    
}
```

It is a very simple model but it holds all your canvases plus the information on which canvas is selected.

Now all that is left is to put it all together:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var scene: CanvasScene = .init(canvases: [.init(width: 10, height: 10, defaultColor: .blue),
                                                           .init(width: 30, height: 30, defaultColor: .green)])
    @State private var selectedColor: Color = .red
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Select canvas", selection: $scene.selectedCanvasIndex) {
                ForEach(scene.canvases.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("Canvas: \(index)").tag(index)
                }
            }
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                CanvasView(canvas: scene.canvases[scene.selectedCanvasIndex])
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                let selectedCanvas = scene.canvases[scene.selectedCanvasIndex]
                                let x = Int(value.location.x/proxy.size.width*CGFloat(selectedCanvas.width))
                                let y = Int(value.location.y/proxy.size.height*CGFloat(selectedCanvas.height))
                                selectedCanvas.applyColor(selectedColor, at: (x, y))
                            }
                    )
            }
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            Spacer()
            ColorPickerView(selectedColor: $selectedColor, colors: [.red, .green, .blue, .orange])
                .frame(height: 60)
        }
        .padding()
    }

}
```

Here you can study how data injection is done, how bindings are used so forth. Feel free to play around with this and change it the way you need to have it.

I hope it clears a few questions that you have. It is not a direct answer to your question but I believe that your approach needs to be adjusted to something more maintainable.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for your response it helps me a lot, im just playing with the code now ..

Comment: if you can help, I trying to retrieve on a next view , the color value useing 
        let current_color = Canvas.colorAt(x: current_number_x ,y: current_number_y )
        pixel.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = current_color , any help with this syntax would b amazing thanks in advance.

Comment: I could do with being able to access the canvases from the next Page

Comment: var x = Int(current_number)
        var y = Int(1)
        var selected = canvases[1]
        var current_color = selected.colorAt(x: x, y: y)
        pixel.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = current_color

Comment: https://github.com/myopengiftcouk/lightning-2-2

Comment: @EdwardTaylor If you need to access your data from somewhere completely unrelated (which seems to be your case) then I suggest that you use singleton pattern. Instead of creating your `CanvasScene` in `ContentView` simply have it a singleton and use it both in `ContentView` and in your other section of the app. `extension CanvasScene {
    static let current: CanvasScene = .init(canvases: ...)
}` and then anywhere use it like `CanvasScene.current`.